# Sentence Similarity Estimate with word2vec

Tags: machine-learning, text-mining

If I have a list of sentences, how can I get a score for the similarity for each pair of sentences using word2vec? Besides, for sentence similarity, is using word2vec better than other methods, such as cosine similarity?

Comment: Did you try doc2vec from gensim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, word2vec produces vector mappings from words to vectors, but doesn’t propose a vector representation for a larger structure such as a sentence. In order to find the similarity between two sentences you need to go from the vector representations of the words in each sentence to a vector representation of each sentence itself. From there you can use the usual vector distance metric (cosine similarity, computer as the dot product of the normalised vectors) to compare them.

It’s up to you how to combine word vectors into sentence vectors, but a simple way would be to add the word vectors all together.